# What is the LP gap of vertex cover in planar graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, approximation-algorithms

What is the LP gap of vertex cover in planar graphs?

The LP I refer to is  min  $\sum_{e \in E } c_e x_e \ \ $   subject to   $ \ \ x_v + x_u  \geq 1 \ \ \ \forall  uv \in E  $
$ c_e \geq 0 $ are costs of the vertices

Also  is there an LP with a smaller gap?

(I posted this in mathstackexchange where it was labelled offtopic if it is offtopic here please tell me where I should post this.)

Comment: Here's the link to the previous version of the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728596/what-is-the-lp-gap-of-vertex-cover-in-planar-graphs I suspect the reason why it was closed on MSE was that you hadn't provided enough background -- e.g. definitions of "LP gap" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming_relaxation#Approximation_and_integrality_gap and the "vertex cover" problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover

Comment: Are there classes of graphs for which you know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertex cover LP gap is $\frac32$ for planar graphs. The $\frac32$ follows by looking at an extreme point optimal LP solution with values in $\{0, \frac12, 1\}$. Let $V_{i}$ be the set of vertices with LP value $i$ for all $i \in \{0, \frac12, 1\}$. Now we create an integral vertex cover. In this vertex cover take all the $V_1 $vertices. Now, look at any $4$ coloring of the graph. This coloring will partition $V_{\frac12}$ into 4 part. Now to our vertex cover, we add all the vertices in $V_{\frac12}$ except the part with a maximum cost.
It is easy to see that what we get is a vertex cover of cost at most $\frac32$ times the LP value.

$K_4$ gives a tight lower bound of $\frac32$.